# React Native: Build apk file using Expo CLI

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

I'm a new learner on this platform.
I code a simple react native app using expo. But I want to build a .apk file.
I tried this command:

```
expo build:android
```

Then I sign up an expo account. After completing the building process it shows the download button.
 Just like the following picture: [image] But its not apk file. It is .aab file.
So, I want to build an actual apk file.
How can I do that?

Comment: Abb is now default

Answer (score 6):

to build a apk out of the file first you need to do some changes to your `eas.json` file.

By default, EAS Build produces Android App Bundle, you can change it by:

- setting `buildType` to `apk`
- setting `developmentClient` to `true`
- setting gradleCommand to `:app:assembleRelease`, `:app:assembleDebug` or any othergradle command that produces APK

after changing the config you can run `eas build -p android --profile preview` to build the application

you can read more about this in docs
https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/

and here's a sample config i used for a basic project to build ( also you can find on docs )

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.52.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

--

also alternatively another possible way would be to get the bundle ( .aab ) file and convert it to apk using a too like bundletool. and you can find the apk ( universal.apk ) inside app.apks

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=bundle.aab --output=app.apks --mode=universal
```

https://github.com/google/bundletool

Comment: Hey, I'm encountering an error in the process. ```package.json does not exist in /home/expo/workingdir/build/client```

Answer (score 3):

By default Expo, CLI builds the app into a `.aab` file format. this format is better for Google Play Store as it will be optimized for every device CPU architecture which results in a smaller app size.

In case you want to test for your device or emulator, run:
`expo build:android -t apk`

Answer (score 3):

### Update for new users:

Run the following:

› `npm install -g eas-cli`

› `eas build -p android` https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

expo build:android will be discontinued on January 4, 2023

Answer (score 1):

From expo documentation :
When building for android you can choose to build APK (expo build:android -t apk) or Android App Bundle (expo build:android -t app-bundle).